# How I can add attribute for particular Image by Jquery Array

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add attribute for my multiple images by jquery array but It's not working. Please help me !

```
<div id="result">    
<img src="Image1" width="300"/>
<img src="Image2" width="300"/>
<img src="Image3" width="300"/>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var imagesArray=[];
$('#result img').each(function() {
imagesArray[1]=$(this).attr({alt: 'Beijing'});
imagesArray[2]=$(this).attr({alt: 'India'});
imagesArray[3]=$(this).attr({alt: 'USA'});  
});


</script>
```

Comment: You declare `arrayVariable` and then use `imagesArray`? You update/overwrite the `imagesArray` on each iteration of the `each()` loop? What end result are you looking for?

Comment: Are you trying to collect the attributes into an array, or assign attributes to the images from an array? Some of this looks pretty backwards, but your question isn't clear enough to provide guidance. What do you want your final markup to represent, and what do you want your array variable to look like in the end?

Comment: The varialble is var imagesArray=[]; @DavidThomas

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ, I have just corrected my question. please help me

Comment: @Siddharth: What do you want `alert(imagesArray[1]);` to display, "Beijing"?

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ: I want to add attribute in first image (Beijing). If I will use imagesArray[2] then I want to add "India" in third image

Comment: The `each()` here doesn't make sense.  Just store the jQuery object in a variable and then use `eq(#)` to get each element in turn to set their attributes.

Answer (score 0):

So what I think you're trying to do is programmatically assign the `alt` text to each of the images *from an array*.

Keep in mind that arrays in JavaScript are 0-based. You don't want to start with the number 1 here.

Here's how your code might look:

```js
var altTexts = ['Beijing', 'India', 'USA'];

var imagesArray = [];
$('#result img').each(function(index) { // add the index parameter provided by each
    $(this).attr('alt', altTexts[index]); // assign the alt-text to the current images from the array
    imagesArray.push(this); // add the image to the imagesArray
});

alert($(imagesArray[0]).attr('alt')); // Test: Beijing
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">    
<img src="Image1" width="300"/>
<img src="Image2" width="300"/>
<img src="Image3" width="300"/>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that this will break if the number of images found does not equal the length of the `altTexts` array. Also, as others have mentioned, you really don't need a loop here unless the number of images is going to be changing.

In short, I would never put code like this in a production environment. It's pretty fragile.

Comment: You could use `this.alt = ...` to save some jQuery object creations, no?  Same thing on the alert.

Comment: @Taplar: Definitely, just didn't want to stray too far from the original post.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ, Thank you so much Your answer is perfect. One more thing I want to know that how I can create "href" Link for images by Jquery array ?? It would be very big favor on me.

Comment: First you will have to wrap your `<img>` tags with `<a>` tags. You could follow the same example, just use "href" for an additional attribute. Preferably you would create an array of objects (e.g. `[ { alt: "Beijing", href: "/test.html" }, ... ]`) and then do `altTexts[index].alt` or `altTexts[index].href` to access the properties for setting. At some point, you might as well create the entire tag structure yourself. I've left out a few details as an exercise for you.